# finite normal minimal

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that the set of all minimal normal subgroups of $G$ is finite and that each of them is also finite. Let M be the product of them all.

My questions is:

If $C_{G}(M)\neq 1$ is true that $C_{G}(M)$ contains a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $G$?

As $C_{G}(M)$ is normal in $G$,I just know that $N\leq C_{G}(M)$ or $N\cap C_{G}(M)=1$, where $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

Help!

Comment: Let $G$ be infinite cyclic. Then $M=1$ and $C_G(M)=G$ contains no minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: $N$ is minimal normal subgroup of G. I'll edit.

Comment: Jack, his group G does not satisfy the assumptions of the problem.

Comment: @JackSchmidt (Edit) Hmm, if there are no minimal subgroups then $M=1$? I suppose that makes sense, and so OP would want at least one minimal normal subgroup to exist in $G$. OP: Ah, so you're saying "$N\le C_G(M)$ or $N\cap C_G(M)=1$ for all minimal subgroups $N$" essentially. That's correct.

Comment: @User2040: $G$ does satisfy the assumptions of the problem. You can also take $G=\mathbb{Z} \times A_5$ as a counterexample.

Comment: That's right!
Why $N\cap C_{G}(M)=1$ does not occur for some N minimal?

Comment: Please, who are $M$ and $C_{G}(M)$ in $\mathbb{Z}\times A_{5}$?

Comment: $M=1 \times A_5$ is the unique possible $N$. $C_G(M) = \mathbb{Z} \times 1$ contains no minimal normal subgroups of $G$. In particular, $N \cap C_G(M)=1$ rather than $N \leq C_G(M)$ for every minimal normal subgroup $N$ (there being only one, $M$).

Comment: User2040: Ok! Thank you!